# Delete unwanted link comment

Tags: discussion, deletion

A user has used a question of mine to reach me on an unrelated topic, [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7629/3260). As you can see, on the comments, he links to another unrelated [post](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/how-to-deal-with-artists-slightly-modifying-free-use-songs-and-becoming-the-defa) and now, the two posts become linked (in the right column) even if they are not related.

Is it possible to delete to comment on a deleted post so we remove this unwanted (unrelated) link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the comment.

As you can see, the questions are no longer linked.